# Angular Different Builds

Tags: angular

I'm using latest version of Angular and have the following issue:

I have an app and want to create two versions: a full version and a demo. By that, I mean I want to create two different builds that will shared the majority of code, but will have a different UI. for simplicity, if I have a toolbar, I want to change it's view based on the version.

What I thought doing is to create an abstract component which is called Toolbar and to make 2 different concrete classes that extend it: FullToolbar and DemoToolbar. In my main html file I will call the same component , but it's implementation will be chosen somehow in compile time. 
Can anyone guide me to achieve the result I want in some way?

I will also add that I want to use a clean solution and compile-out unnecessary classes and functionality. For example, If I have a user management service/component in my full version, I want noting of it to remain in the demo version.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that you use NX to build 2 differents apps, Demo and Prod, you can use libs to share code between the 2 apps

[image]

this will help you to have a monorepo for your 2 apps and optimize your builds.

for more details [nrwl NX](https://nrwl.io/nx)