# How to convert Whole Component to library?

Tags: angular

Want to convert Component to a library but not using npm publish. We don't want to publish it publically. Is there any other solution for creating module/Component to the library?

Comment: What about `npm link`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185842/4399281 you can use NX it has a nice structure, you can share code in libs

Comment: You can run your private repository - no need to publish publicly.